# Find a minimum value in a column element in a numpy array, and store corresponding row as a new array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array like below, and I would like to make a new numpy array which has a row that has the minimum value in the last column which is element of `xx[:,4]`.

```
xx =
[[6.18167195e-02 -3.20902583e-01  7.96803103e+00   5.69096614e+00  6.82949858e+00]
[1.14139479e-02 -2.93352490e-02  5.17031336e+00   2.50552347e+01  1.51127740e+01]
[8.84761009e-03 -2.93352490e-02  1.84764173e+01   2.50552347e+01  2.17658260e+01]
[1.96567549e-03 -2.93352490e-02  8.18878876e+01   2.50552347e+01  5.34715612e+01]
[3.54827629e-01 -1.88511194e+00  4.70728062e-01   1.95791971e-01  3.33260017e-01]
[3.53146766e-01 -1.88511194e+00  9.42210619e-01   1.95791971e-01  5.69001295e-01]
[6.64244146e-02 -3.20902583e-01  1.10815151e+00   5.69096614e+00  3.39955882e+00]
[6.18167195e-02 -3.20902583e-01  7.96803103e+00   5.69096614e+00  6.82949858e+00]
[1.95005819e-02 -1.40482917e-01  2.64188251e+00   1.63546768e+00  2.13867510e+00]
...
...]
```

I know that we can use `np.min(xx[:,4])` to get `3.33260017e-01` in the last column.
However, I need to extract all values in the corresponding row, which will be this

`[3.54827629e-01 -1.88511194e+00  4.70728062e-01   1.95791971e-01  3.33260017e-01]`.

In a multidimensional array, such as `xx.shape = (1000,4)`, how can I get the element locations of the minimum value?

My question is either one of them.

1. Make a new numpy array only with the row that has the minimum value in the last column.
2. Delete every rows except the row that has the minimum value in the last column.

Comment: `xx[xx[:, -1].argmin()]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>>
>>> xx = [[6.18167195e-02,-3.20902583e-01,7.96803103e+00,5.69096614e+00,6.82949858e+00],
... [1.14139479e-02,-2.93352490e-02,5.17031336e+00,2.50552347e+01,1.51127740e+01],
... [8.84761009e-03,-2.93352490e-02,1.84764173e+01,2.50552347e+01,2.17658260e+01],
... [1.96567549e-03,-2.93352490e-02,8.18878876e+01,2.50552347e+01,5.34715612e+01],
... [3.54827629e-0,-1.88511194e+00,4.70728062e-01,1.95791971e-01,3.33260017e-01],
... [3.53146766e-01,-1.88511194e+00,9.42210619e-01,1.95791971e-01,5.69001295e-01],
... [6.64244146e-02,-3.20902583e-01,1.10815151e+00,5.69096614e+00,3.39955882e+00],
... [6.18167195e-02,-3.20902583e-01,7.96803103e+00,5.69096614e+00,6.82949858e+00],
... [1.95005819e-02,-1.40482917e-01,2.64188251e+00,1.63546768e+00,2.13867510e+00]]
>>>
>>> xx = np.asarray(xx)
>>>
>>> def MinRow(array):
...     low = np.min(array[:,4])
...     for idx, el in enumerate(array):
...         if el[-1] <= low:
...             index = idx
...     newarray = array[index, :]
...     return newarray
...
>>> xx2 = MinRow(xx)
>>> print(xx2)
[ 3.54827629 -1.88511194  0.47072806  0.19579197  0.33326002]
```

Pure Numpy Solution:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>>
>>> xx = [[6.18167195e-02,-3.20902583e-01,7.96803103e+00,5.69096614e+00,6.82949858e+00],
... [1.14139479e-02,-2.93352490e-02,5.17031336e+00,2.50552347e+01,1.51127740e+01],
... [8.84761009e-03,-2.93352490e-02,1.84764173e+01,2.50552347e+01,2.17658260e+01],
... [1.96567549e-03,-2.93352490e-02,8.18878876e+01,2.50552347e+01,5.34715612e+01],
... [3.54827629e-0,-1.88511194e+00,4.70728062e-01,1.95791971e-01,3.33260017e-01],
... [3.53146766e-01,-1.88511194e+00,9.42210619e-01,1.95791971e-01,5.69001295e-01],
... [6.64244146e-02,-3.20902583e-01,1.10815151e+00,5.69096614e+00,3.39955882e+00],
... [6.18167195e-02,-3.20902583e-01,7.96803103e+00,5.69096614e+00,6.82949858e+00],
... [1.95005819e-02,-1.40482917e-01,2.64188251e+00,1.63546768e+00,2.13867510e+00]]
>>>
>>> xx = np.asarray(xx)
>>> idx = np.where(xx[:,4]==np.min(xx[:,4]))
>>> xx2 = xx[idx]
>>> print(xx2)
[[ 3.54827629 -1.88511194  0.47072806  0.19579197  0.33326002]]
```

Comment: Please post all your code as text rather than screenshots of text. Images are not consistently formatted correctly across devices, and are impossible for assistive technologies such as screen readers to interpret.

Comment: Thanks @Aaron. Will fix.

Comment: @Kris Your answer was very helpful! and it worked! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

`argmin` will give you the index where the minimum value is.

```
>>> xx=np.array([[2,1,3],[1,0,2],[3,3,1]])
>>> xx
array([[2, 1, 3],
       [1, 0, 2],
       [3, 3, 1]])
>>> column = 1
>>> i = xx[:,column].argmin()
1
>>> xx[i,:]  # get the row where column 1 has the minimum
array([1, 0, 2])
```

Comment: This does more work than necessary, you only need to do `argmin` on the relevant column (`xx[xx[:, i].argmin()]`).

Answer (score 1):

You're nearly there, you want `np.where`

```
idx = np.where(xx[:, -1] == np.min(xx[:,4]))
output = xx[idx]
```

Comment: `np.argmin(xx, axis=-2)`: more concise, and less computation.

Comment: need to change to: `idx=np.where(xx[:,4] == np.min(xx[:,4]))`

Comment: Ah, you're right, my test I used -1 there, not sure how I converted to a zero here...